# Erlang like msgbox event loop

Tags: python, message, communication, msgbox

I want to implement Erlang like messaging, unless already exists.
The idea is to create multiprocess application (I'm using Ray)

I can imagine how to do the send/recv :

```
@ray.remote
class Module:

    def recv(self, folder, msg ) : 
        if folder not in self.inbox : self.inbox[folder] = deque()
        self.inbox[folder].push(msg)

    def send(self, mod, folder, msg): mod.recv(folder,msg)
```

You call .send() which remotely calls the target module .recv() method

my problem is i dont know how to do the internal eventloop that REACT on messages.

It has to be lightweight too, because it runs in every process.

One idea is while-loop with sleep, but it seems inefficient !!

Probably, when msg arrives it has to trigger some registered FILTER-HOOK if message matches ? So may be no event loop needed but just routines triggered by FILTER !!!

Answer (score 0):

What i did for now is trigger a check routine every time i get a message, which goes trough rules defined as (key:regex, method-to-call) filters